# can't have a file larger than 10*10 characters

Tags: java

what makes it only be able to input 10*10 text files

```
package game;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Level {

static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("Data1.txt");
    int[][] m = Map(f);
    for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(m[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int[][] Map(File f) throws IOException {

    ArrayList line = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String s = null;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line.add(s);
    }
    int[][] map = new int[line.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        s = (String) line.get(i);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
        int[] arr = new int[st.countTokens()];
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        map[i] = arr;
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

if i put in a text file that is 
10*10 or less characters it works
otherwise it comes out with a numberformatexception

fixed

package game;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Level {

    static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("Data1.txt");
        int[][] m = Map(f);
        for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < m[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print(m[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] Map(File f) throws IOException {

        ArrayList line = new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String s = null;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.add(s);
        }
        int[][] map = new int[line.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            s = (String) line.get(i);
            char[] m = s.toCharArray();
            String[] n = new String[m.length];
            for (int t = 0; t<m.length;t++)
            {
                n[t] = ""+m[t];
            }

            int[] arr = new int[m.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(n[j]);
            }
            map[i] = arr;
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line do you get your numberformatexception on? Also, I recommend `String.split(String regex)` over using `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: Where is the NumberFormatException thrown from, the `Integer.parseInt()`? Also, give an example of your input file.

Comment: 33: for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

Comment: Is Your program J2ME? If Yes: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f),10*10);` Just try to increase the buffer data.

Comment: What happens if you use a `Scanner` to read the file instead of a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: what the problem is that whenever the text file has more than 10 characters per line it throws a NumberFormatException.

Comment: Well, I'd say the NumberFormatException is coming from Integer.parseInt() because int (or Integer) has a max value of 2,147,483,647.  When you remove the commas, you have 10 characters.  So it stands to reason that 11 characters in a string is going to be out of an Int's range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to notes in the comments, your program seems to work with large files, and with long lines, as long as there are enough spaces.

I think your issue is actually that whenever the text file has a token with more than 10 characters it throws a NumberFormatException.

That would be because `Integer.MAX_INT` is 2147483647, which has 10 characters when written as a String, and `Integer.parseInt` just can't handle more digits than that.

You're splitting on space and expecting everything to parse as an integer, and some of your numbers are too big for Java's integer data type.

Answer (score 0):

Int's max value is: 2,147,483,647 or 2147483647 without the commas.  That's 10 characters.  attempting to parse an 11 character string to an int would result in a number that is beyond the Int's max value, hence, the NumberFormatException.